# What does "break out the layer cake" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In this sentence:

> For taxi drivers staring down an even bleaker future of driverless
>   cars at a moment when Washington considers a weekly paycheck bump of
>   $1.50 an occasion to **break out the layer cake**, it is hard to see
>   where the metaphoric Prozac will come from.

Does "the layer cake” refer to somebody here?

Comment: The phrase you have highlighted is made of two distinct pieces, 'break out the X' and 'layer cake'. A good explanation will separate the two.

Comment: Of course, [the cake is a lie](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-cake-is-a-lie).

Comment: Probably worth attributing this quote to https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/06/nyregion/livery-driver-taxi-uber.html

Answer (score 4):

A layer cake is a fancy cake often eaten at celebrations. So to 'break out the layer cake' is to have a celebration.

Comment: Yeah, though "break out" is an established idiom, "break out the layer cake" is not (and phrases like "break out the champagne" would be more common).  But most NES would understand what was meant.